# CMake ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET with SOURCES

Tags: xcode, cmake

I'm trying to add source files to a custom target (minizip) in my Xcode project. From here on, "doesn't work" means source files not appearing under the target within the Xcode project navigator, while "works" means that they do.

Works:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(minizip SOURCES "${<path_to_minizip_dir>}/unzip.c")
```

Doesn't work:

```
FILE(GLOB MINIZIP_SRC "${<path_to_minizip_dir>}/*")
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(minizip SOURCES ${MINIZIP_SRC})
```

Doesn't work:

```
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY("${<path_to_minizip_dir>}" MINIZIP_SRC)
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(minizip SOURCES ${MINIZIP_SRC})
```

How do I get it to worK? I.e, have all the sources from the minizip directory included within the target, without having to specify each one individually.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Removed the quotes as follows and it works.

```
FILE(GLOB MINIZIP_SRC ${<path_to_minizip_dir>}/*)
```